# How to run Selenium Webdriver tests in mac

Tags: java, macos, selenium, webdriver

I have written tests using Eclipse IDE using Java language. Then I convert it into Executable Jar and send it to a client(customer) machine. The client machine is Mac and He wants to run it on Mac. For that JRE has to be installed

Is there an alternative other than installing installing JRE. What is the preferred method to run same tests in different machines. Is python or Javascript a good option.

I would like to know what is the preferred way to run same tests in different machines with minimum downloads/installations .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JRE is quite comfortable cause it works everywhere.
But if you don't want it check for:

-Excelsior JET

-Launch4j

Still, for me best option would be installing jre, cause it makes sure it will work

Comment: It is best to use JRE, but customer does not want to do so. He will try it on windows machine. I wanted to know hoe do others run selenium on mac Python, C# or any other lang that is easy.